# How do we effectively use mind maps (or anything similar) to demonstrate key areas (to test & impacted) while planning testing of complex new feature?

Tags: manual-testing, documentation, test-planning, test-strategy, strategy

I was recently testing a new feature that impacts all most the entire application. While I was trying to communicate the business impact to my team I found it difficult to emphasize on it by the testing plan or documentation I prepared. What are the effective ways to use mind maps and exhibit key business areas and impacted areas so that everyone in the team gets a clear picture?

Comment: I would create  a mind map using two colors .One for impacted areas and one for not and will discuss/present it to the entire team.

Answer (score 2):

My personal suggestion is:

1. Before making a decision to use mind map (or anything similar), talk to the business people. Learn about how they visualize a business idea / a feature. They may use a completely different tool, in this case, you will need to improvise.
2. Mind map is a great tool to show insightful relations, but each person has a different logical mind, by presenting a mind map out of blue may not help much. How about organize a session with the business people and walk them through your mind map, showing them how you dissect this business features into different level of objects and how they relate to each other.
3. Mind map is not the silver bullet. Since you mentioned testing plan and business impact, you may need to consider using other tools as well.

For a few technicality on how to use mind map, please follow this [link](https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2013/09/how-to-use-mind-maps-to-unleash-your-brains-creativity-and-potential/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my personal suggestion

Our mind easily understand even a complex feature if we will explain in pictorial format

1. Use more images instead of words while explaining the complex feature
2. You can also prepare the checklist which will help to figure out the
   Impacted areas easily.

Please check this [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mindmup-20-free-mind-map/mkgkheknpfngchmoaognoilfanomldfl?hl=en). I have used this to achieve better quality when the complex feature has been implemented in our projects.